# Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, gettext

I'm trying to create a login for an application. However I have a problem.

This is my code:

```
package com.forgetmenot.loginregister;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText uname, password;
    Button submit;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG = "Login";

    JSONObject json;
    private static String url_login = "http://localhost:8080/ForgetMeNotApplication/Login";
   //JSONArray incoming_msg = null;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       findViewsById();
       submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
               // execute method invokes doInBackground() where we open a Http URL connection using the given Servlet URL
               //and get output response from InputStream and return it.
                new Login().execute();

           }
       });
    }
    private void findViewsById() {

        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    }
    private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Getting username and password from user input

            String username = uname.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u",username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p",pass));
            json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET", params);
            String s=null;

            try {
                s= json.getString("info");
                Log.d("Msg", json.getString("info"));
                if(s.equals("success")){
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), home.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Android studio says that method `getText()` must be called from the UI Thread at the istructions: `uname.getText().toString();` and  `password.getText().toString();` Possible solutions??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to pass Your values to `Login AsyncTask`  via `execute(param1, param1, ..., paramN)` method:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

               String username = uname.getText().toString();
               String pass = password.getText().toString();
               new Login().execute(username, pass);

           }
       });
    }
    private void findViewsById() {

        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    }
    private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Getting username and password from user input

            String username = args[0];
            String pass = args[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

make `username` and `pass` `login` class variable and override `onPreExcecute()` and do this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        username = uname.getText().toString();
        pass = password.getText().toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the UI thread from a background thread here:

```
String username = uname.getText().toString();
String pass = password.getText().toString();
```

What you want to do is just pass the username/password strings in to your background task constructor or you could pass them directly to the execute method. I prefer to define them in to the constructor if they are going to be required (like yours are).

Define your LoginTask like

```
String uname;
String password;
public Login(String username, String password({
    this.uname = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Then in doInBackground() you use the members instead.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u",this.username));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p",this.pass));
json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET", params);
```

Edit - so then your new Login().execute() call would look more like this

```
new Login(uname.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless something has changed that I'm not aware of, that shouldn't be a problem. UI elements can't be updated from the background but accessing their getters has never been an issue.

Anyway, you can get around this by adding a constructor to your `AsyncTask` which would take the two `String`s then send them when creating your task.

```
private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    // member variables of the task class
    String uName, pwd
    public Login(String userName, String password) {
        uName = userName;
        pwd = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {...}
```

and pass them in your `onClick()`

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // execute method invokes doInBackground() where we open a Http URL connection using the given Servlet URL
     //and get output response from InputStream and return it.

     // pass them here
     new Login(uname.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).execute();
 }
```

Comment: On my API 19 device, I found that `getText()` seems to work but other methods, like `TextureView`'s `getBitmap()`, crash.

Comment: I think `getText ` can be access in work thread, it is only the ide hint, not the runtime exception

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because `doInBackground()` is invoked from a background thread. I would add two String parameters to the constructor of your `Login` class.

I would like to advise you to gain more knowledge about `AsyncTasks` and Threading on Android. For example, there is a page in the official docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html.

You might also take a look at this course: https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853. You can learn a lot of basics of the Android framework.