# method getText must be called from the ui thread

Tags: android, json

I am doing an application that need to send data from android to database. I am doing it using JSONParser. But I got problem when I launched the application, it doesn't send the data to the server. I got and error on "String name = inputName.getText().toString();". Here is it:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String date = inputDate.getText().toString();
            String time = inputTime.getText().toString();
            String latitude = inputLatitude.getText().toString();
            String longitude = inputLongitude.getText().toString();
            String contacts = inputContacts.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contacts", contacts));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, you cannot call `getText()` on a background thread. Instead, move your six `getText()` calls into a constructor of your `AsyncTask`, or possibly into an `onPreExecute()` callback, so the `getText()` calls are made on the main application thread.

Comment: Or use `Handler` that was created on the main thread, and from the background thread call the handler's `sendMessage` method.

Comment: @t0mm13b: Not from within `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`. The rest of `doInBackground()` needs the data before proceeding.

Comment: I have the found the solution to settle the problem. This is the link [lhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011996....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011996/method-gettext-must-be-called-from-the-ui-thread-android-studio?rq=1). But it still doesn't send the data to the server. Whether the error is related to the that or there is some mismatch problems in the server?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry but *this is not at all clear to me*.