# Android Studio Error: Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm working on app which shows the lyrics of song. And I have got an error: Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread. I was searching for answer, but no answer has helped solve the problem.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText wykonawca;
private EditText tytul;
private Button pokazTekst;
private TextView tekst;

//String url = "http://www.tekstowo.pl/piosenka,";
String title;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    FindViews();



    tekst.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); // mozliwosc scrolowania tekstu

    pokazTekst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new SongText().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class SongText extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    String url = "http://www.tekstowo.pl/piosenka,";
    String author;
    String song_name;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // here is error
            author = wykonawca.getText().toString();
            song_name = tytul.getText().toString();

            url = url + author + "," + song_name + ".html";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            title = doc.select("div[class=song-text").text();
        }

        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        tekst.setText(title);
    }
}

private void FindViews(){

    // Edit text
    wykonawca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wykonawca);
    tytul = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tytul);

    // Buttons
    pokazTekst = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pokazTekst);

    // TextViews
    tekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst);

}
```

}

Comment: You're calling getText() from an asynchronous thread. It should be called from the UI thread. What you can do is get the value from the textfields before calling the asynctask and read the value from string variables or pass them in to the asynctask constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with UI elements off the UI thread. doInBackground() runs on a background there and you cannot interact with a textview in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the UI thread from a background thread here:.

```
author = wykonawca.getText().toString();
song_name = tytul.getText().toString();
```

Check this SO answer-
[Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011996/method-gettext-must-be-called-from-the-ui-thread-android-studio)